# How can I remove lines from a csv that do not meet a criteria in two fields in powershell?

Tags: csv, powershell

I am trying to write a one line script to take in a csv file, and then export every line that does not have a $file.Source starting with "10." and a $file.Destination starting with a "10.". This is the code I have so far:

```
Import-Csv $importFile | where -NotMatch {$_.Source.StartsWith("10.1") -and $_.Destination.StartsWith("10.")} Export-Csv $exportFile
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good case for using the `-not` operator within the context of your [`Where-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) clause.

For example:

```
Import-Csv $importFile | 
where {-not $_.Source.StartsWith("10.") -and -not $_.Destination.StartsWith("10.")} |
Export-Csv $exportFile
```

If there's a chance that your `Source` and `Destination` columns will come through with a numerical datatype, you can call `.ToString()` on their values before invoking `.StartsWith()`.

```
Import-Csv $importFile | 
where {-not $_.Source.ToString().StartsWith("10.") -and -not $_.Destination.ToString().StartsWith("10.")} |
Export-Csv $exportFile
```

**Tip:** If you want to see the results of your `Where-Object` filtering before exporting the CSV file, you can replace `Export-Csv $exportFile` with `ConvertTo-Csv`. That cmdlet simply returns the raw CSV string.